# Load src javascript from file on click

Tags: javascript, external, src

I am trying to load a .js file into a div that is located in a folder on my desktop when I click a link.  I will have 100's of js files.  I do have the

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="Apple.js"></script>
```

in there, but there will be 100's of these where the page will start to load slow if I have all of these in there in the html file.  Is there a way I can have the page load quickly, then when I click on the link go out and retrieve the individual js file?  When the page loads I will have another js file that will be retrieving all of the links.  Can I somehow put this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="Apple.js"></script>
```

in the

```html
<a onclick="GetApple();"/>Apple</a>
```

so when clicked it knows what file and where to retrieve it?

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TITLE HERE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="LinksList"> 
    <a onclick="GetApple();"/>Apple</a>
  </div>
  <div id="ScriptList"> 
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="GetLinks.js"></script>  ```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Apple.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    GetLinksList()
  }
</script>
````

Comment: JavaScript running in a browser is forbidden from accessing your desktop. Imagine the security issues that would be created if it could.

Comment: are you trying to display the contents? download the file? execute the file? if the answer is you're tryin to execute the file then the answer is bad idea, security nightmare, don't do it. In all cases you cannot access the computers filesystem directly the files need to be hosted before they'll be accessible and all 3 options become possible.

Comment: Hi danielRicado, appreciate the response.  If you go here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77669099/load-src-javascript-that-has-multiple-src-scripts-inside   my issue with this approach is when the page loads the "function include(filePath)" I am going to have 100's of .js files that will take a little bit to load.  I was just wondering if there was a way instead of loading all of those at once, I could click the link in the html and it would go out and display/load the specific .js file I clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a `<script>` tag to page having the `src` as the `url` of the file. Please note that this is asynchronous action. Here's an example with a nice wrapper.

```js
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69616316/3807365
function addScript(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const s = document.createElement('script');

    s.setAttribute('src', src);
    s.addEventListener('load', resolve);
    s.addEventListener('error', reject);

    document.body.appendChild(s);
  });
}


document.querySelector(".my-button").addEventListener('click', async function(ev) {
  await addScript(ev.target.getAttribute("data-src"))
  console.log("jquery loaded!", $)
  $(ev.target).css("background", "red")

})
```

```html
click to <button class="my-button" data-src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">load jquery</button>
```